# SP2010 Passing Value to New Item Form Modal using Client Object Model/SPD

Tags: client-object-model, form, spservices, modal-dialog

Beginner. I have a list form that opens from page using SP.UI.ModalDialog. The form is to represent entries into a description list based on ID from parent list. The page has tabs that allow user to first make an entry to the parent list, then select the next tab which using jQuery/SPServices to grab the last ID from the parent list and load a bunch of information relative to the second tab page. From this page the user can click a link which calls the dialog and add multiple entries to the child list....so its like a very basic one to many I have trying to retain.

I already have the parent's ID from the SPService portion of the script, and the value is shown on the page. What I can't figure out is how to pass that value into the Modal New Item Form. Everything works fine if I manually add the value (parentID) into each entry of the child's new item, but this defeats the purpose. I just trying to pass a number to the form...can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone else is just getting started and runs into this as I did, here is how I was able to get this working.

Found solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/sharepoint2010general/thread/1f54adf5-2211-4fa0-aa5c-a72cb120df23) that worked for me.

Link above help me with getting the value from the qs, and setting the formfield with that value. Already had the ParentID and qs; used jquery for that.